# Connecting to remote desktop through ssh instead of RDP

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, remote-desktop

So I have a company laptop with windows that is on the same network (vpn) as my office desktop (windows).

I can connect to the office desktop using RDP but is there a way for me to connect through SSH using putty or OpenSSH ?

Right now, when I specify the hostname through putty, it seems to be be able to create the connection but when it asks me to login, I would use the same username as my windows RDP username but I later get an error that says:

"Network error: Software caused connection abort"

How can I connect to my office desktop if I can connect using RDP ?

Comment: Has your IT restricted what ports you can connect over - so maybe they allow RDP but not SSH?  Can you ping the device you are trying to connect to, or connect to any other port on it?  Does the machine you are connecting to even have an SSH server running on it for you to connect to [that's not an out of the box thing for Windows - for instance].

Comment: I’ll reach out to IT about restricting the connection type. For pinging the device, is there a way for me to do so ? I was able to get the connection established when I use putty or OpenSSH, but then I got the above error for putty. When I use openssh, I get a message saying “connection reset by [ip-address]”. I’ll also have to check to see if it has SSH server running (is there a way to find out ?)

Comment: Open windows command prompt and type `ping machinename` [where machinename is the name you put in to connect to it].  If that gives you packets lost, then probably IT have some filtering or are only allowing connection to certain ports.

Comment: Turn on putty verbose mode, and connect then perhaps [check the event log](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/using-eventlog.html) .. I've never looked at it, but it supposedly has all the "stages" of connection - so if it fails right at the start I'd say you don't have an SSH server.

Comment: I expect you'll need to be an admin if you want to install an SSH server - if you don't have admin privileges on the box -  IT will need to fenangle something for you.

Comment: So I tried to ping the desktop, and there was 0 packets lost, would this mean that there is no filtering but rather that there is no SSH server set up ? Does this mean that RDP and SSH Server are completely different (ie: being able to use RDP does not mean you have a SSH Server..). I saw that one way to set up SSH server is to use OpenSSH Server right ?

Comment: Correct they are unrelated.  RDP is a "screen sharing" protocol - which has been the root cause of quite a few nasty security problems lately (lessan issue on VPN if home machine is secure).  Banks like RDP because it's just like a video (there's not much user data to easily sniff - you have to derive things from the video).  SSH provides a secure pipe, over-which people mostly run a terminal connection - i.e. like command prompt ... you can use it for making connections to other machines (port forwarding) or the local machine (say RDP is locked down to external access)... putty is ssh client

Comment: @MrR Yes, I see. So to fix this I just need to set up a ssh server on the machine right ? Also, is it typically the case that a ssh-server is already created on linux ? Usually you don’t need to do anything in order to ssh into the machine

Comment: there's nothing "broken" per-se with not having SSH on your windows machines (it's just the way they ship).  On linux I think you have to enable it, but there are minimal defaults that need to be configured, and the philosophy is command line much more than GUI.  Similarly for OSX (although most people need never see the command line on OSX under the covers it is a FreeBSD derivative - which more and more "protection" for GUI only users as time goes by).